# Time Difference in Siebel Application and Database

Tags: utc, siebel

I have a problem where I can see time is not same in application and in database.

For example, record that has been created from UI has time '10/21/2014 07:49:12 AM'. Where as, the same record when queried in database has the time '10/21/2014 11:49:12 AM'.

As we can see, there is a time difference of 4 hours.

We have set UTC parameter to FALSE and re-started the siebel web server. But, we haven't restarted the siebel server and load balancing server.

Answer (score 0):

Siebel server's default timezone is set at Application->System Preference level: "Default Time Zone". Siebel will adjust the values from DB tables accordingly. In addition, users may specify their own timezone at Employee level. Check these places to see if something is set.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already noticed, Siebel stores the date and time values in UTC. When a user enters a date, it's internally translated to UTC before saving it to the database; when it's recovered in a business component, it's translated back to the current user's timezone. As *Ranjith R* said in his answer, each user may specify it's own timezone in his/her profile, otherwise the `Default Time Zone` system preference applies.

The decision whether to use UTC times or not, must be made before deploying the servers. Once the application is set up and running, as it appears to be your case, the change from UTC to non-UTC **is not supported**.

There is a full chapter dedicated to UTC dates and times, on the *Siebel Deployment Guide* of the Siebel Bookshelf. [Here is the link for Siebel 8.0](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/GlobDep/GlobDepUTC2.html). Amongst other things, they state the following:

> CAUTION: Once you have already deployed your Siebel applications using UTC and created user date-time data in UTC format, it is not supported to stop using UTC by setting the Universal Time Coordinated system preference to FALSE. Otherwise, incorrect time stamp values may be created and displayed.

Apparently, there is a UTC conversion utility intended to update historical data from non-UTC format to UTC, but it doesn't work the other way around.